# ios objC call back calling method

Tags: objective-c, c, callback

Im using System sound services, to play a sound I have recorder with the microphone,
is working fine, and using a callback when the sound stops,

```
//callback pa saber termina
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (soundID,NULL,NULL,completionCallback,(void*) self); //q es un call back?, q es (void*)self??

//Use audio services to play the sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

so when the sound stops it calls:

```
//usando Callback!
static void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* myself) {
 NSLog(@"termino");
}
```

But how can I call my method:

```
- (void)stopSoundByDemand{
self.playingMode = NO;
[self.playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self stopSound];
 }
```

So if I understand correctly "callbacks" are only for C?

How can I call then from this C "callback" the objC method?

I have read about it but haven't figured out,

please I need clarification on what a callback is, if is only for C,

and how to call the method,

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `[(id)myself stopSoundByDemand]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self is your object .. to know of it in the callback function *which is not part of your class* you pass it as a (void*) to the function in form of the context parameter.

now to get back to your object and call the method you take that pointer from the context var

**in your case**
context is named myself:
`[(id)myself stopSoundByDemand];`

---

a callback in general is a function that does not belong to any instance and therefore doesn't know about self.